# What category of math does the Fourier Transform fall into?

Tags: calculus, computer-science, fourier-transform, finance, data-analysis

I am a recent MS in CS grad with an emphasis in Data Science and I have decided I want to learn college-level math so I may apply it to specialized DS/CS problems in the future (optimization algorithms, NN architecture) and better understand DS procedures. I know a very small amount of calculus as it applies to gradient descent and stats/ML models. While I have the time and resources (I am currently unemployed and living with my parents), I have decided to take Single/Double Var Calc, Differential Eqs, and Linalg from MIT open course-ware. I have a couple questions..

(1) where in my journey will I learn about Fourier Transformations and Wavelet Transforms? I am reviewing them now for DS and was wondering where they will come along.

(2) Is there any other math classes I should plan on taking to succeed in a DS/CS career? I also have an interest in finance, and plan on taking a quantitative finance from MIT after these courses..

(3) Is there any math in particular (past these pre-reqs for the QF class) which would fall in line with the typical track for a quantitative analyst?

I appreciate any response– I am just trying to gauge the breadth of mathematics that will be of practical use to me in the future. I know these are rather open ended questions– an answer to the first will suffice. Thank you!

Comment: Technically, real analysis, complex analysis, harmonic analysis. But for your purpose the level of formality that you'll find in books with those titles may not be so useful. Sadly I don't have suggestions for books to get practitioners basically up to speed on how methods are used without a bunch of rigorous development.

Comment: In the grand scheme of things, Fourier transforms fall into [Harmonic Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_analysis), though in my experience going at it from that perspective tends to be pretty abstract (reqs measure theory, topological group theory, etc.).

Comment: 1) Fourier Transform is very important also for applied fields (image processing, optics, etc..). You will hopefully meet as well its less gifted cousin, Laplace Transform, mainly used for solving differential equations. 2) For your objective in Data Science, I recommand you the recent book by Gilbert Strang "Linear Algebra and learning from Data" (https://www.amazon.com/Linear-Algebra-Learning-Gilbert-Strang/dp/0692196382). All the books, all conférences, done by G. Strang (prof. at MIT) are very accessible..